# Clojurescript: Error: Could not find or load main class clojure.main

Tags: clojurescript

I installed Clojurescript following its [quick start guide](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start).

I pulled the git repo to `~/clojurescript`.
`CLOJURESCRIPT_HOME` is set `~/clojurescript` and `clojurescript/bin` is added to system path.

When I try to use commands `cljsc` I get following error

`Could not find or load main class clojure.main`

How can I solve it?

Comment: To run the ClojureScript compiler you need to have Clojure installed.

Comment: i do have clojure installed through lein. Clojure works fine.

Comment: Ok. Try to create a lein project based on a ClojureScript template. [lein-mies](https://github.com/swannodette/mies) is a minimal ClojureScript project template and [chestnut](https://github.com/plexus/chestnut) uses Om and have a pretty solid browser REPL experience. I believe this quick start guide is for people intended to develop ClojureScript itself not for application development in ClojureScript.

Comment: I had a similar problem just now. I thought I'd downloaded the standalone jar (which currently is step 1 of the quick start guide), but I had not. It's supposed to be 19M while my file was just 387 bytes. After downloading the file jar correctly everything works fine.

Comment: totally agree with I3dx, the standalone clojurescript (19Mbyte) comes with clojure included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright coming back after 5 years.

This error surfaces when one runs `clj --main cljs.main --compile hello-world.core --repl` from directory or path which does not have file `deps.edn` or `cljs.jar`.

Considering the directory structure at https://clojurescript.org/guides/quick-start,

```
hello-world  #### Run that command in this directory
├─ src   
│  └─ hello_world
│     └─ core.cljs 
├─ cljs.jar 
└─ deps.edn
```

i.e.

```
$ cd hello-world
$ clj --main cljs.main --compile hello-world.core --repl
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going through this tutorial today.

I checked here for this error. The version of the standalone jar was correct. The problem was caused by a 'typing mistake' in the core.cljs file. The string "Hello world!" was not in **double quotes**. Initially the string was in single quotes and included a comma.

The other issue I struggled with was getting the java command to work. I was using a Cygwin64 Terminal.

The correct command for the Cygwin64 Terminal is:

```
$ java -cp "cljs.jar;src" clojure.main build.clj
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was typing Windows command by mistake which has `"` in the command + make sure you'll have the `cljs.jar` in your root folder bes

`java -cp cljs.jar:src clojure.main build.clj`

I hope it helps someone, one day.:)

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your project using leiningen then your project cli would look something like this

```clj
(defproject clojuredemo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]]
  )
```

After the :dependencies add the following lines

```
 :jar-name "<project-name>.jar"
 :jar-path "/target/<project-name>.jar"
```

Note : you need the replace the project name with your project

After that run the following command

```
lein jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the JAR file at classpath exists:

```
java -cp target/missing-file.jar clojure.main your.namespace
```

will confusingly throw `Could not find or load main class clojure.main`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error after trying to run an uberjar file that I compiled using clojure build tools. The problem was that I forgot to add the `(:gen-class)` key to the `ns` call:

```
(ns my.namespace
  (:require [...])
  (:gen-class))
```