# How to setup clojure.main?

Tags: installation, clojure, windows-10, leiningen

In reference to the thread here : [Clojurescript: Error: Could not find or load main class clojure.main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481272/clojurescript-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-clojure-main)

Where (in which directory) do we need to keep the clojure.jar? Should it be in the lein folder or in the folder where lein folder exists?

I am trying Clojure for the first time and have already spent a large amount of time in setting up Clojure and lein. But still facing the same error.

Comment: Since there is no need to bother with fetching/placing the clojure.jar somewhere, when leiningen is used, it would really help, if you think, that your problem is different from the one you liked to also add what you have tried and how it failed. Also add versions for the relevant gears in motion (java, leiningen, are you using WSL, ...).

Comment: I've used clojure-1.7.0, leiningen-2.7.1 and jdk-1.8

Comment: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.home=C:\Users\<username>
Error: Could not find or load main class clojure.main

Comment: `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\NewLocCProject\myproject>lein repl`  <br/>
`C:\Users\<username>\Documents\NewLocCProject\myproject>java -classpath ""C:\Users\<username>\lein\2.7.1\leiningen-2.7.1.jar"" clojure.main -
m leiningen.core.main repl`  <br/>
`Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.home=C:\Users\<username><br/>
Error: Could not find or load main class clojure.main`  <br/>
This error persists

Comment: hey, @cfrick. I have added few more details

Comment: Please don't add errors and versions as comment. Please edit the question. Also what is the result of `lein repl`? Is this `java -cp ...` line something you entered after an error? Please also provide the `project.clj` of your project and also the relevant files beside that (e.g. a file tree)

Comment: Are you using Windows 10 directly or Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)? While you can run Clojure on Windows 10 directly, you will find it a lot easier if you use WSL.  If not, take a look at https://github.com/clojure/tools.deps.alpha/wiki/clj-on-Windows or the #clj-on-windows channel on the Clojurians Slack.

Answer (score 1):

Open a project with `lein`

```
$ lein new myproject
$ cd myproject
```

There in `src/<projectname>/core.clj`
put your code - and from inside this myproject folder
start `lein`:
`lein repl`
It will run the core.clj code - and say sth like:

```
nREPL server started on port 46297 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:46297
```

So you can connect with this repl from emacs using
`M-x cider-connect` and choose `localhost` and as port `46297` or whatever is given as port in that nREPL line!

Answer (score 0):

Please see this template project for a good way to get started

- https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template

Follow the instructions in the README file.  An excerpt:

```
How to Use This Project

To use this project, we assume you have already installed Java, Clojure, and Leiningen, and git.

Clone the Project Using Git.
Verify you have Git installed:

> git --version
git version 2.25.0

Use git to clone the project (via SSH) into a new project names demo:

> git clone  git@github.com:io-tupelo/clj-template.git  demo  # git ssh URL

or, clone via HTTPS (if you don’t have SSH set up on your computer & GitHub):

> git clone  https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template.git  demo  # git https URL

Then cd (change directory) into the new project:

> cd demo

Verify you have Java, Clojure, and Leiningen set up correctly
Try the following commands, and make sure you get similar output:

> java --version
java 13 2019-09-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13+33)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13+33, mixed mode, sharing)

> lein --version
Leiningen 2.9.1 on Java 13 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

....etc....